# Automatically scroll div

Tags: vue.js

How do I, with Vue, scroll down a div to a specific place? I have a list < li > inside a < div > and I want Vue automatically to scroll down to the active item. I know the height of each item, so it's basically x position from top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**position div to X location**

basicly change such div's `top` value.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.top = "100px";
```

**scroll entire page to X coordinate:**

first number is x another y. So if you know position - just

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Thanks. Guess that's the way to do it with v-el.